# page reload after login instead of redirecting to another page

Tags: asp.net

I have a website running on asp.net . We integrate our website with our partners using iframe.

When our login is open in iframe, the user fills out the form and clicks on signup. After that button is clicked, the same login page reloads. This problem only occers on Chrome. On other browsers ,such as Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox, everything works fine.

The error I got in the console in chrome is [image]

Comment: Your image is not shown here.

Comment: Please post the error directly into the question. Do not post it as an image.